# How to print position in array when printing content of an array?

Tags: java

First, sorry if title is misleading or unclear, I'm new to Java and I couldn't find the correct way to describe it.
Below is a piece of my code, I have 3 classes, housing, management, and mainTest.

housing.java

```
public class housing {
    private String occupantsName;
    private double price;

    public housing() {
        occupantsName = "Noone";
        price = 100.00;
    }
    
    public housing(String name, double pricing){
        occupantsName = name;
        price = pricing;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        occupantsName = name;
    }
    public void setPrice(double pricing){
        price = pricing;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return occupantsName;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Room occupied by " + occupantsName + " is priced at " + price;
    }
}
```

management.java

```
public class management {
    private housing[] house;
    private int c;

    public management(){
        house = new housing[7];
        c = 7;
    }

    public management(int noOfRoom){
        if (noOfRoom>0&&noOfRoom<=10){
            house = new housing[noOfRoom];
            c = noOfRoom;
        }
        else{
            house = new housing[7];
            c = 7;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<c;i++){
            house[i] = new housing();
            if ((i|1)>i&&i!=0){
                house[i].setPrice(150.00);
            }
        }
    }
    public String displayEven()
    {
        String all = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<c;i++)
        {
            if ((i|1)>i&&i!=0)
                all = all + house[i].toString() +"\n";
        }
        return all;
    }
}
```

mainTest.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class mainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        management bad = new management(5);
        System.out.println(bad.displayEven());
    }
}
```

Current output when I run the program:

```
Room occupied by Noone is priced at 150.0
Room occupied by Noone is priced at 150.0
```

Is there any way to give an identifier representing the position of the data in the array index? In this case they are [2] and [4]. For example, something like:

```
2. Room occupied by Noone is priced at 150.0
4. Room occupied by Noone is priced at 150.0
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the array index in the constructor of `housing`? Btw, class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: ...if you want to add `i` to the string then just do it. `all = all + i + ". " + house[i].toString() +"\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just how Guy Incognito discribed it change this

```
public String displayEven()
{
    String all = "";
    for (int i = 0;i<c;i++)
    {
        if ((i|1)>i&&i!=0)
            all = all + house[i].toString() +"\n";
    }
    return all;
}
```

to this

```
public String displayEven()
{
    String all = "";
    for (int i = 0;i<c;i++)
    {
        if ((i|1)>i&&i!=0)
            all = all + i + ". " + house[i].toString() +"\n";
    }
    return all;
}
```